# Creating questions based on bug reports on others (non-SE) sites

Tags: discussion, scope

Lately, I've been seeing a lot more questions that have such specific code examples in them and such an edge case bug report that I wonder if they are based on actual findings of the author by using the specific piece of software or they just to "plagiarized" a recently reported (high profile) bug on Github issues, public JIRA etc.

The fact this bothers me is because these questions generally get a lot of up-votes and community attention but they aren't really the work of the SO author. They just harvest the fruits of somebody else his hard (debugging) work. What should we do in these cases (if it's crystal clear somebody based their whole question around a (recent) bug report)?

Comment: That is called plagiarism and  can be flagged for a moderator to investigate if you include the source where it is plagiarized from.

Comment: Is the idea that the OP is pretending to not know their issue is actually a bug?

Comment: I normally VTC these as unreproducible. If you found the bug, then you have the ability to apply the patch, and if you don't then why should SO hijack the ranking from the bug tracker itself?

Comment: @Braiam Even if the bug is in something like a compiler?

Comment: Of course, specially if it's the compiler the faulty component. SO isn't a bug tracker, nor it should aim to be. Bugs, specially if reproducible should live in their respective bug trackers, along with debugging procedures, workarounds, etc.

Comment: Is it frowned upon to ask "trivia" questions? Because some of these seem like trivia questions...

Comment: Trying to confirm you found a bug, go for it.  Showing off a bug you found, write a blog post and file a bug report.